# how to get ajax response from view cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am using **cakephp2** and working with ajax , well i have successfully get the response of ajax request form controller action but i am not getting the response from view to success method.
Here is my code.
Code For ajax Request:

```
 var data = new Array(maincatagory,subcatagory,experience,degree,city,area);
    ajaxfunction(data);
    function ajaxfunction(d){

        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(d);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/FindTutor/posts/searchresults",
            data: {data : jsonString},
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){

                alert(data);

            }

        }).fail(function(){
            alert('request fail');
        });
    }
```

Now here first I get array and pass to data after jasonStringfy.
Now In posts/searchresults action:

```
public function searchresults(){

    if( $this->request->is('ajax') ) {
        $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
        $this->request->onlyAllow('ajax');

        $this->set(compact('data')); // Pass $data to the view
        $this->set('_serialize', 'data');
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
  die();
 }
}
```

And Now in searchresults view I am doing this:

```
<?php foreach($data as $d){
echo $d;
```

} ?>
But I am not getting the data back or responce from view.
Another Thing is If i echo data in controller action I get the responce successflly,Like this,

```
 public function searchresults(){

    if( $this->request->is('ajax') ) {
        $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
        $this->request->onlyAllow('ajax');
        <?php 
           foreach($data as $d){
            echo $d;
          } 
         ?>
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
  die();
 }
}
```

Help me I'm really stuck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using log console?

Comment: What do you expect when you let your code `die` before anything is being rendered?

Comment: You should use RequestHandler and request the page with a .json extension in which case you would not need a view file or set the layout. See: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html . And $this->request->onlyAllow is deprecated. The results should be available in $this->request->data as long as you have set the request headers correctly.

Comment: @unixmiah ... console.log is also empty.

Comment: got it worked .. problem was i was using die() method at end of the action that does not set the data to view file. 
@ndm thanks for mentioning.